# Unexpected character (A) at position 0

Tags: java, android, json, io

Here is my json file from mysql server.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/studyabroad/university.php on line 18

```
Array[{"code":"100654","name":"Alabama A & M University",
"type":"public","city":"Normal","state":"AL",
"logo_url":"http:\/\/www.logosurfer.com\/sites\/default\/files\/university-of-california-logo_0.png",
"percentage":"53"},

{"code":"100706","name":"University of Alabama in Huntsville",
"type":"public","city":"Huntsville","state":"AL",
"logo_url":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/commons\/b\/b2\/Ashford_University_Full_Color_Logo.png",
"percentage":"82"}]
```

my parsing code is

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try{

        BufferedReader bfReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        bfReader.readLine();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while((line = bfReader.readLine())!= null){
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        line = builder.toString();
        Object obj = parser.parse(line);

        return obj;

    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ParseException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }finally{
        try{
            is.close();
        }catch (IOException ex){
            //later handler it.
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

in my server side to convert the result to json format I used

```
json_encode($data);
```

The cause of the error is the format of json data. `Array[{..},{..}]` instead of `[{...},{..}]`.
Is there any way I can change the format of json data from above to 
`[{...}, {...}]` or how do I parse the given format?

Comment: please elaborate this difference [{..},{..}] instead of [{...},{..}].

Comment: i think he means that everytime there is a JSONArray, it appends Array before the [ ]

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Substring to get the values succeeding tha Array part:

```
line = builder.toString().substring(5);
```

Comment: I am assuming there are no internal arrays ... If there are please specify so that i can adjust the logic :)